# Obtener id del item actual con vanilla js

Tags: php, javascript

cordial saludo a todos.
Tengo el siguiente problema, tengo una lista de `<a>`  con datos traídos de la DB, cada `<a>` tiene un `<a id="numero">` que es el numero id de la DB, quiero obtener ese id para con el evento onClick mostrar un formulario para añadir un registro a la DB y poder insertar ese mismo id a la DB en otra tabla a través de ese formulario.

```html
<aside class="main-panel">
    <div class="logo-main-panel">
        <img src="<?php echo constant('URL') ?>assets/img/logo.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="btn-main-control">
        <button id="btn-create-serie">Crear Serie</button>
    </div>
    <h4 align="center">Lista de series</h4>
    <nav class="main-nav-panel">
        <?php
            foreach ($this->series as $row) {
                $genero = new Series();
                $genero = $row;
        ?>
            <a id="serie-<?php echo $genero->id; ?>"><?php echo $genero->titulo; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </nav>
</aside>
```

Como podrán ver tengo un `foreach` que mapea todos los datos por medio de `<a>` y como explicaba, quiero mostrar un formulario con `valor.style.display = "flex"`  y enviar la id obtenida como otro `<input type=hidden value="idObtenida">` más el resto de datos que ingrese.

Comment: Tienes un HTML mal formado, abres `<a ..` y cierras `</option>`. Por favor edita la pregunta para corregir y podamos saber exactamente cómo lo estás intentando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

primero deberías escuchar los eventos click de esos elementos, creo que sería una buena idea aplicarle una class, por ejemplo "edit-reg" a todos los  que quieres escuchar, en el ejemplo uso querySelectorAll para buscar todos los elementos con esa clase y luego itero el resultado para escucha los clicks sobre estos, y finalmente extraigo el id del mismo.

```javascript
function onClickHanlder(event){
  console.log(event.target.id);
  mostrarFormulario(event.target.id)
}
var links = document.querySelectorAll(".edit-reg")
links.forEach(el => el.addEventListener("click", onClickHandler)
```

Answer (score 2):

No se si te refieres a obtener el ID, Del objeto clickeado por el usuario, puedes ver y obtener muchas propiedades de un elemdto del DOM, con .target, aqui hay un ejemplo

```js
document.getElementById("ejemplo1").addEventListener("click", function(event){
  alert(event.target.id)
  
})
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML, CSS and JavaScript demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Start your code here -->

<button id="ejemplo1" >Hola</button>

<!-- End your code here -->
</body>
</html>
```

Puedes  obtenerNodeValue, Value, id, name y muchas cosas mas con target

Aqui hay mas informacion: https://www.it-swarm.dev/es/events/que-propiedades-puedo-usar-con-event.target/939867192/